# Get the program menu on Cocoa program

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu

ALL,

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436395/how-i-can-get-the-application-menu-in-cocoa) which answer my question perfectly.

However, I need some clarification. AFAIU, [itmeAtIndex: 0] will give the reference to the Apple menu and not to the application menu. I'm talking about the menu which a little Apple sign displayed on the menu bar. Or this Apple menu is not countable in this case and the application menu is located at position 0?

A little OT: it had been MY experience that trying to comment on the old question nobody will ever try to reply. So I made this new thread here hoping that someone will notice it and reply.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want to access your app's menu ? In MainMenu.xib you can find the `MainMenu` which is your apps menu.

Comment: The link I referenced does not talk about resources. I'd like to do it from the code.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the Apple menu is not included in the menu returned by mainMenu (which is usually defined in the xib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple menu with the apple logo is not included in the menu returned by mainMenu (which is usually defined in the xib), which is specific to your application.